# Element to stick to bottom of other element

Tags: javascript, html, css

So what Im trying to achieve is to make a div element stick onscroll to nav header element bottom but they are not in the same parent, also the header dissappear onscroll down and re-appear onscroll up
this is the link to codepen

https://codepen.io/snake220/pen/VwdwpwJ

```css
.red-div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.green-div {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.test2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.blue-div {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="red-div"></nav>
<div class="green-div">
  <div class="test2"></div>
  <div class="blue-div"></div>
</div>
```

so like showin in the code I want the blue div to stick under the red div onscroll.

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to set `position: sticky` and `top` equal to the red nav height which equal to 50px like `top: 50px;`

```css
.red-div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}

.green-div {
   background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.test2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.blue-div {
  background-color:blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="red-div"></nav>
<div class="green-div">
  <div class="test2"></div>
  <div class="blue-div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Mina and Thanks for your answer, but I can't set `top: 50px;` since the red div  disappear with scroll down (in my real code) and with the top 50px and the blue div will stay 50px away from the top. what I need is when the red div disapear with scroll, the blue one sticks to the top of the screen.